# Clion cannot open output file, permission denied

Tags: c++, permissions, clion

So I'm trying to run some c++ code on Clion, but every time I try to use it to read a file this happens:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Collin\Documents\School\C++\exercises\3.smartIO\cmake-build-debug --target 3_smartIO -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable 3_smartIO.exe    
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file 3_smartIO.exe: Permission denied
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    CMakeFiles\3_smartIO.dir\build.make:95: recipe for target '3_smartIO.exe' failed
    mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [3_smartIO.exe] Error 1
    CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/3_smartIO.dir/all' failed
    mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/3_smartIO.dir/all] Error 2
    CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/3_smartIO.dir/rule' failed
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/3_smartIO.dir/rule] Error 2
    Makefile:117: recipe for target '3_smartIO' failed
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [3_smartIO] Error 2
```

From my understanding this means it cannot open the files because of permission issues. I tried checking if the file already is running (which isn't the case), I tried to delete it before running, that doesn't work either.

I also thought me saving it in Google drive might be the problemen, but this also occurs when its not in drive.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
I read somewhere that error code 1 means the task is still running.
I have looked at the task manager but I cannot find the program running.

Edit:
alright, just tried to restart my laptop, this did work. That means the problem really is that the program is still running at the moment I try to run it. The new question is: Why can't I find any traces of it?

Comment: How did you check that it wasn't running? Did you open the task monitor to make sure there wasn't a lingering process?

Comment: Used the task monitor and process explorer, unless I'm forgetting something I would say that it should be that hard to find if it was still running

Comment: alright, just tried to restart my laptop, this did work. That means the problem really is that the program is still running at the moment I try to run it. The new question is: Why can't I find any traces of it?

Answer (score 0):

More probably, that your target file 3_smartIO.exe protected by another running process, so , did you try to turn it (clion) off and on again ? It should help you.

Comment: It should be comment instead of posting it as an answer